# Why is my Line Chart not displaying (Chart.JS)?

Tags: jquery, html, chart.js, linechart, chart.js2

I'm displaying a pie chart and a bar chart, but my line chart, with the same type of code, does not display, and I wonder why. Here is my code:

HTML

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.3/Chart.js"></script>
. . .
<canvas id="forecastLineChart"></canvas>
```

JQUERY

```
    var lineChartData = {
            labels: [
                "APPLES, GALA WAXF 138", "APPLES, GOLDEN DELICIOUS WAX
100", "APPLES, GOLDEN DELICIOUS WAXF 113"
            ],
            datasets: [
                {
                    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                    strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
                    highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
                    highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    data: [49, 46, 153.86]
                },
                {
                    fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                    strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
                    highlightFill: "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
                    highlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                    data: [52, 40, 65.00]
                },
                {
                    fillColor: "rgba(120,240,180,0.5)",
                    strokeColor: "rgba(120,240,180,0.8)",
                    highlightFill: "rgba(120,240,180,0.75)",
                    highlightStroke: "rgba(120,240,180,1)",
                    data: [42, 42, 227.70]
                }
            ]
        }
        var ctxLineChart = $("#forecastLineChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
        var forecastImpactLineChart = new    Chart(ctxLineChart).Line(lineChartData);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax to define a chart has changed a bit in version 2.  [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c4uw37re/).

```
var forecastImpactLineChart = Chart.Line(ctxLineChart, {
    data: lineChartData
});
```

OR

```
var forecastImpactLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: lineChartData,
    options: options
});
```

Answer (score 1):

typo in the code (missing the "w" from new):

```
 var forecastImpactLineChart = new Chart(ctxLineChart).Line(lineChartData);
```

Comment: Only in the post, not in the actual code; I'll fix the post to better reflect reality.